# Enabling moderation for SharePoint list

Tags: content-approval

In List Definition, in `elements.xml` `ListTemplate` element has `EnableModeration` attribute.

From MSDN:

> EnableModeration - 
>   Optional Boolean. TRUE to specify that content approval is enabled by default in lists created through the template; otherwise, FALSE.

Also in `schema.xml`, the `List` element has `ModeratedList` attribute

> ModeratedList - 
>   Optional Boolean. TRUE to require content approval for submitted items.

What is the difference? Which one should I set to have `Approve/Reject` button available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope differs, the effect should be the same. One is used in List instances (per instance of list - even when using the OOTB lists, you might want to have it created  with Content Approval enabled) by example, the other is used in List Definitions, e.g. when you create a new List Template and want to enforce this by default, then you can omit it from List instances.

C:\Marius